# General closed form of $\int_{.5}^{1} e^{-\frac{c^2}{2\cos^2(\pi u)}} u^{a-1}(1-u)^{b-1} du$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

General closed form needed for

1)$$I_{c}(a,b)=\int_{.5}^{1} e^{-\frac{c^2}{2\cos^2(\pi u)}} u^{a-1}(1-u)^{b-1} du$$

2)$$J_{c}(a,b)=\int_{0}^{.5} e^{-\frac{c^2}{2\cos^2(\pi u)}} u^{a-1}(1-u)^{b-1} du$$

Dominated CT theorem guarantee that $I_{c}(a,b)$ and $I_{c}(a,b)$ exist. Simulation studies confirm it.

My try that "FAIL": <<<------

\begin{eqnarray}
I_{c}(a,b)&=&\int_{.5}^{1} e^{-\frac{c^2}{2\cos^2(\pi u)}} u^{a-1}(1-u)^{b-1} du \\
&=&\int_{.5}^{1} (\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-\frac{c^2}{2\cos^2(\pi u)})^n}{n!} ) u^{a-1}(1-u)^{b-1} du
\\
&=& \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n!} (\frac{-c^2}{2})^n\int_{.5}^{1} 
\frac{1}{\cos^{2n}(\pi u)}
u^{a-1}(1-u)^{b-1} du
\end{eqnarray}

but how to calculate 
\begin{eqnarray}
L=\int_{.5}^{1} 
\frac{1}{\cos^{2n}(\pi u)}
u^{a-1}(1-u)^{b-1} du
\end{eqnarray}

Information:
 the integral for L won't converge for n≥1. (tnx to robjohn)

R code:   it may help:

```
   a<<-3;b<<-3
   cc<<-1

   fn<-function(u){
   temp.e<-(cc^2)/((2*cos(pi*u))^2)
   ret.value<-exp(-temp.e)*dbeta(u,a,b)*beta(a,b)
   return(ret.value)
   }
   integrate(fn,lower=.51,upper=1)
   # output 
   #> integrate(fn,lower=.51,upper=1)
   #0.004973315 with absolute error < 3.3e-06
```

My second try:

if I find a Taylor series for $e^{-\frac{c^2}{2}\tan^2(\pi u)}$ like
$$e^{-\frac{c^2}{2}\tan^2(\pi u)}=\sum \frac{a_n}{n!}u^n$$ 
so it will help. since

$$J_{c}(a,b)=\int_{0}^{.5} e^{-\frac{c^2}{2\cos^2(\pi u)}} u^{a-1}(1-u)^{b-1} du$$

$$=\int_{0}^{.5} e^{-\frac{c^2}{2}(1+\tan^2(\pi u))} u^{a-1}(1-u)^{b-1} du$$

$$=e^{-\frac{c^2}{2}} \int_{0}^{.5} e^{-\frac{c^2}{2}\tan^2(\pi u)} u^{a-1}(1-u)^{b-1} du$$

$$=e^{-\frac{c^2}{2}} \int_{0}^{.5} \sum \frac{a_n}{n!}u^n u^{a-1}(1-u)^{b-1} du$$

$$=e^{-\frac{c^2}{2}} \sum \frac{a_n}{n!} \int_{0}^{.5}  u^{n+a-1}(1-u)^{b-1} du$$

$$=e^{-\frac{c^2}{2}} \sum \frac{a_n}{n!} B(n+a,b) B(.5,n+a,b)$$

Comment: In order to get responses that suit your needs, please include **in the body of the question** your own thoughts, the effort made so far, and the specific difficulties that got you stuck.

Comment: Tnx for your attention. I added some explanation

Comment: It seems that $I_c(a,b)=J_c(b,a)$, so once you have a closed form for $I_c$ you are done.

Comment: I'm glad you took the advice. This is now a great question.

Comment: Since $\sec^2(\pi u)$ blows up as $u\to\frac12$, I don't think the series representation of $e^x$ is going to be the way to go. For instance, the integral for $L$ won't converge for $n\ge1$.

Comment: if I change L by enter $n!$ in it.

Comment: @masoud: dividing $\infty$ by $n!$ still leaves $\infty$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT**

$\color{brown}{\textbf{Preliminary notes.}}$

Substitution $v=1-u$ show that $I_c(a,b) = J_c(b,a)$ (**robjohn**).

Let us consider the second integral in the form of
$$J_{c}(a,b) = \int\limits_0^{^1/_2}e^{^{\Large -\frac c2
\csc^2 \frac\pi2 \sqrt{1-4v\large\mathstrut\ }}}
u^{1-a}(1-u)^{1-b} \,\mathbb du,\tag1$$
where
$$v = u(1-u)\tag2$$ 
and $J_0(a,b)$ can be presented via Incomplete Beta Function.

Calculations of the integral $(1)$ in the closed form in the general case looks too hard. 
It can be useful to get the integral in the series form.

$\color{brown}{\textbf{Laurent series of the cosecant square part.}}$

Is known that

> $$\csc^2 z = \sum\limits_{k=-\infty}^\infty \dfrac1{(z-k\pi)^2},\tag3$$
>   $$\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty k^{-n} = \zeta(2n)
>  = \dfrac{2^{2n-1}\pi^{2n}}{(2n)!}\left|B_{2n}\right|\tag4,$$

where 
$\zeta(n)$ is Riemann zeta function and $B_n$ are the Bernoulli numbers.

Taking in account $(2)-(4),$ one can get
\begin{align}
&\csc^2 \frac\pi2 \sqrt{1-4v\large\mathstrut\ } 
- \dfrac4{\pi^2(1-4v)}\\[4pt]
& = \dfrac4{\pi^2} \sum\limits_{k=-\infty}^\infty \dfrac1{\left(\sqrt{1-4v\large\mathstrut\ }+2k\right)^2} - \dfrac4{\pi^2(1-4v)}\\[4pt]
& = \dfrac4{\pi^2} \sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty \left(\dfrac1{\left(2k-\sqrt{1-4v\large\mathstrut\ }\right)^2} + \dfrac1{\left(2k+\sqrt{1-4v\large\mathstrut\ }\right)^2}\right)\\[4pt]
& = -\dfrac{8}{\pi^2} \sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty \dfrac {4k^2+1-4v}{(4k^2-1+4v)^2} 
= \dfrac{8}{\pi^2} \sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty\dfrac {8k^2-(4k^2-1+4v)}{(4k^2-1+4v)^2} \\[4pt]
&= -\dfrac{8}{\pi^2} \sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty \dfrac1{4k^2-1+4v} 
 - \dfrac{16}{\pi^2} \sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty \dfrac {\mathrm d}{\mathrm dv}\dfrac {4k^2}{4k^2-1+4v} \\[4pt]
&=\dfrac8{\pi^2} \sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty\dfrac1{4k^2}\dfrac1{1-\dfrac{1-4v}{4k^2}}
-\dfrac{16}{\pi^2} \sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty \dfrac {\mathrm d}{\mathrm dv}\dfrac{1}{1-\dfrac{1-4v}{4k^2}}\\[4pt]
&=-\dfrac{8}{\pi^2} \sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty  \sum\limits_{j=0}^\infty\dfrac{(1-4v)^j} {(2k)^{2j+2}}
-\dfrac{16}{\pi^2} \sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty  \sum\limits_{j=0}^\infty\dfrac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dv}\dfrac{(1-4v)^j} {(2k)^{2j}}\\[4pt]
&=-\dfrac{8}{\pi^2} \sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty  \sum\limits_{j=0}^\infty\dfrac{(1-4v)^j} {(2k)^{2j+2}}
+\dfrac{16}{\pi^2} \sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty  \sum\limits_{j=0}^\infty\dfrac{(j+1)(1-4v)^j} {(2k)^{2j+2}}\\[4pt]
&=\dfrac1{\pi^2} \sum\limits_{j=0}^\infty (4j+2)\left(\dfrac{1-4v}4\right)^j\ \dfrac{2^{2j+1}\pi^{2j+2}}{(2j+2)!}|B_{2j+2}| \\[4pt]
&=2\sum\limits_{j=0}^\infty \dfrac{|B_{2j+2}|}{(j+1)(2j)!}\left(\pi^2(1-4v)\right)^j.
\end{align}

This leads to the Laurent series in the form of
$$\csc^2 \sqrt t =\dfrac1t 
+ \sum\limits_{j=0}^\infty s_j t^{j},\quad t\in\left(0, \dfrac{\pi^2}4\right),\tag5$$

where
$$s_j = \dfrac{2^{2j+1}|B_{2j+2}|}{(j+1)(2j)!}\tag6$$
(see [Wolfram Alpha table](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%7B%282%5E%282k%2B1%29+%7CBernoulliB%5B2k%2B2%5D%7C%29+%2F+%28%282k%29%21%28k%2B1%29%29+%7D%2Cwhere+k%3D0%2C1%2C2%2C3%2C4%2C5%2C6%2C7) via $(6)$).

[image: Secant square series]

Since the coefficients $(6)$ decreases faster than $\dfrac1{\pi^2},$
then the series $(5)$ converges quickly (see also [Wolfram Alpha plot](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%20%7Bcsc%5E2%28sqrt%20t%29%20-%201%2Ft%2C%201%2F3%281%2B%20t%281%2F5%2Bt%282%2F63%2B%20t%281%2F225%2B%20%202t%2F3465%281%2B2537t%2F61425%29%29%29%29%29%7D%2C%20%7Bt%2C0%2Cpi%5E2%2F4%7D) for the fifth-order polynomial part).

[image: Secant square approximation]

$\color{brown}{\textbf{Maclaurin series for the regular exponential  multiplier.}}$

Searching of Maclaurin series in the form of 
$$e^{^{\Large -\frac c2 \left(\csc^2\sqrt t - \frac 1t - \frac13\right)}} = 1+\sum\limits_{i=1}^\infty p_i t^{i} \tag7$$

leads to the identity
$$-\dfrac c2 \sum\limits_{j=1}^\infty s_j t^j = \ln\left(1+\sum\limits_{i=1}^\infty p_i t^{i}\right),$$

or, after differentiation,
$$-\dfrac c2\sum\limits_{j=0}^\infty (j+1)s^\,_{j+1} t^j = \dfrac{\sum\limits_{i=0}^\infty (i+1)p^\,_{i+1} t^i}{1+\sum\limits_{i=1}^\infty p^\,_i t^i},$$
$$2\sum\limits_{i=0}^\infty (i+1)p^\,_{i+1} t^i
= -c\sum\limits_{j=0}^\infty (j+1)s^\,_{j+1} t^j 
-c\sum\limits_{j=0}^\infty (j+1)s^\,_{j+1} t^j \sum\limits_{i=1}^\infty p^\,_i t^i\\
= -c\sum\limits_{j=0}^\infty (j+1)s^\,_{j+1} t^j 
-c\sum\limits_{m=1}^\infty t^m \sum\limits_{j=1}^m
js^\,_j p^\,_{m-j},$$

$$2\sum\limits_{m=0}^\infty (m+1)p^\,_{m+1} t^m
= -c\sum\limits_{m=0}^\infty(m+1)s^\,_{m+1} t^m 
-c\sum\limits_{m=1}^\infty t^m \sum\limits_{j=1}^m
js^\,_j p^\,_{m-j},$$

with the recurrency relations in the form of
$$p_0 = 1,\quad p_m = -\dfrac c{2m} \sum\limits_{j=1}^m
js^\,_j p^\,_{m-j}.\tag8$$

If $c=2,$ then from $(6),(8)$ should
\begin{align}
&p^\,_1=-s^\,_1 = -\dfrac1{15},\\
&p^\,_2 = -\dfrac12(s^\,_1p^\,_1+2s^\,_2) = \dfrac12 s^2_1-s^\,_2 = -\dfrac{79}{9450},\\
&p^\,_3 = -\dfrac13(s^\,_1p^\,_2+2s^\,_2p^\,_1+3s^\,_3) = -\dfrac16s^3_1+s^\,_1s^\,_2-s^\,_3 = -\dfrac{13}{15750},\dots,
\end{align}

in accordance with [Wolfram Alpha series expansion](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=expand+e%5E%28-csc%5E2+sqrt+t+%2B+1%2Ft%2B1%2F3%29+near+0)

[image: WA series expansion]

and [graphic confirmation](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%20%7Be%5E%28-csc%5E2%28sqrt%20t%29%20%2B%201%2Ft%20%2B1%2F3%29%2C1-t%2F15-79t%5E2%2F9450-13t%5E3%2F15750%7D%2C%20%7Bt%2C0%2Cpi%5E2%2F4%7D)

[image: Confirmation of the polynomial approximation]

$\color{brown}{\textbf{Transformation of the integral.}}$

Approximation of the regular exponential multiplier via Maclaurin series [is possible for the arbitrary permissible value](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=expand%20e%5E%28c%2F2%28-csc%5E2%20sqrt%20t%20%2B%201%2Ft%2B1%2F3%29%29%20near%200) of the parameter $c.$ Recurrence relations $(8)$ allow to obtain Maclaurin series of the arbitrary length in the general form.

At the same time, substitution 
$$t=\dfrac\pi2-\pi u$$

allows to write
\begin{aligned}
&J^{[n]}_c(u) = \dfrac1{\pi\sqrt[3]e}\int\limits_0^{^\pi/_2}
e^{^{\large -\frac c{2t^2}}} 
\left(1+\sum\limits_{i=1}^n p_i t^{2i} \right)
\left(\dfrac12-\dfrac t\pi\right)^{1-a}
\left(\dfrac12+\dfrac t\pi\right)^{1-b}\,\mathrm dt.
\end{aligned}

For example, in the hard case $a=0.9,\ b=0.8,\ c=2$ [numeric calculations](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int_0%5E.5%20e%5E%28-sec%5E2%20%28pi%20u%29%29u%5E.1%281-u%29%5E.2%20du) give $J_c(a,b) \approx 0.0600752.$ Polynomial [approximation with the five terms](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int_0%5Epi%2F2+e%5E%28-1%2F3+-+1%2Ft%5E2%29%281-t%5E2%2F15-79t%5E4%2F9450-13t%5E6%2F15750-118543t%5E8%2F1964655000%29%281%2F2-t%2Fpi%29%5E.1%281%2F2%2Bt%2Fpi%29%5E.2%2F+pi+dt) gives $J^{[4]}_c(a,b)\approx 0.0600756.$

The factor $\left(\dfrac c4-\dfrac{t^2}{\pi^2}\right)^g$ can be transformed via the polynomial transformation, and this is a last success. The singularity looks too strong.

I cannot get suitable polynomials for the other factors and to get series both via incomplete Beta-functions, in the first case, and via the exponents, integral logarithms, the error function and Gamma-function, in the second case.

**Who can do that?**

Answer (score 1):

Let us set
$$K_c(a,b):=I_c(a,b)+J_c(a,b).$$
For $c=0$, we get
$$K_0(a,b)=\int_{0}^{1} u^{a-1}(1-u)^{b-1} du=B(a,b),$$
where $B(a,b)$ is the Beta function. From this we can expect that there is no closed form unless if special functions are allowed.