# A Hypergeometric identity

Tags: hypergeometric-function

For $a,b>0,m\in \{1,2,3,...\}$ 
$$
\frac{a*m
 \pi}{a+b}\;{}_2F_3\left(
\frac{a+1}{2},\frac{a+2}{2};
\frac{3}{2},\frac{a+b+1}{2},\frac{a+b+2}{2};
\frac{-m^2\pi^2}{4}
\right) \\
=\frac{-i}{2} ( {}_1F_1(a;a+b;i m \pi)-{}_1F_1(a;a+b;-i m \pi))
\\
=\frac{1}{\mathbf{B}(a,b)}\int_{0}^{1} u^{a-1} (1-u)^{b-1} \sin (m\pi u) du
$$

1) Is there a simpler proof of this relation than the one here?  [$I_k=\int_0^1 \frac{1}{\mathbf{B}(\alpha , \beta )} \cos^k (\pi \theta) \theta^{\alpha -1} (1-\theta)^{\beta -1}d\theta $](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3498463/442) .

2) For what domain of $m$ it is true? is it work for not integer values?

[A Hypergeometric Puzzle](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3539314/a-hypergeometric-puzzle) is another question that extracted from [$I_k=\int_0^1 \frac{1}{\mathbf{B}(\alpha , \beta )} \cos^k (\pi \theta) \theta^{\alpha -1} (1-\theta)^{\beta -1}d\theta $](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3498463/442)

R code

```
a<<-4
b<<-3
m<<-5
#
fn<-function(u){
ret<-sin(m*pi*u)*dbeta(u,a,b)
return(ret)
}
## 1F1
U<-c(a)
L<-c(a+b)
z<-(m*pi)*1i
-((1i)/2)*(genhypergeo(U,L,z) -genhypergeo(U,L,-z))
integrate(fn,lower=0,upper=1,abs.tol=1.7e-10)
#output
#> -((1i)/2)*(genhypergeo(U,L,z) -genhypergeo(U,L,-z))
#[1] -0.02945569+0i
#> integrate(fn,lower=0,upper=1,abs.tol=1.7e-10)
#-0.02945569 with absolute error < 1.9e-12
#2F3
U2<-c((a+1)/2,(a+2)/2)
L2<-c(3/2,(a+b+1)/2,(a+b+2)/2)
z2<--(m^2)*(pi^2)/4
((a*m*pi)/(a+b))*genhypergeo(U2,L2,z2)
 #> ((a*m*pi)/(a+b))*genhypergeo(U2,L2,z2)
#[1] -0.02945569
```

Comment: Why do you ask if the identity is true when you post a link to a proof of it???

Comment: I edit my post in both pages

Comment: And why would you ask if the relation is "new" given that you link to a proof of it???

Comment: I dont know it is new or not? a simpler proof will be nice. this relation is not  obvious in the  title of last question so it can not be seen by who search for it (relation between generalized hyper geometric function) in google! but if you think  it is not enough i will delete it.

Comment: You asked if the *relation* is "new" knowing full well that it has already been proven.  Don't you see an inconsistency in that?

Comment: what you recommending to be in title?