# simplify ${}_1F_1(2\alpha , 2 ,ik\pi) +{}_1F_1(2\alpha , 2 ,-ik\pi)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, definite-integrals, hypergeometric-function

1)Is it possible to simplify

$$J_{k,\alpha}={}_1F_1(2\alpha , 2 ,ik\pi) +{}_1F_1(2\alpha , 2 ,-ik\pi)$$

$k\in \{1,2,\cdots\}$ and $\alpha \in (0,1)$. ${}_1F_1$ is [confluent hypergeometric functions of the first kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confluent_hypergeometric_function)(Kummer's function).

I know $J_{k,\alpha}$ is real valued.

```
library(hypergeo)

Jk<-function(k,alpha){
U<-c(2*alpha)
L<-c(2)
z<-1i*k*pi
return(genhypergeo(U,L,z)+genhypergeo(U,L,-z))
}
> Jk(1,.2)
[1] 1.336592+0i
```

there are some value for $J_{(k,\alpha)}$
\begin{array}{c|ccccccccc}
\alpha = &0.1& 0.2& 0.3& 0.4 &0.5& 0.6& 0.7 &0.8 &0.9 \\
\hline
k=1 & 1.70 & 1.34 & 0.92 & 0.47 & 0.00 & -0.47 & -0.92 & -1.34 & -1.70 \\ 
k=2 &  1.41 & 0.85 & 0.40 & 0.10 & 0.00 & 0.10 & 0.40 & 0.85 & 1.41 \\ 
k=3 &  1.32 & 0.77 & 0.39 & 0.16 & 0.00 & -0.16 & -0.39 & -0.77 & -1.32 \\ 
k=4 &  1.23 & 0.65 & 0.27 & 0.07 & -0.00 & 0.07 & 0.27 & 0.65 & 1.23 \\
\end{array}

by definition

$${}_1F_1(a , b ,z)=\frac{\Gamma(b)}{\Gamma(b)\Gamma(b-a)}\int_0^1 e^{zu} u^{a-1} (1-u)^{b-a-1} du=
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(a)_n}{(b)_n} \frac{z^n}{n!}$$

where $(a)_n=a(a+1)\cdots(a+n-1)$.
so
$${}_1F_1(2\alpha , 2 ,z)=\frac{1}{\Gamma(2\alpha)\Gamma(2-2\alpha)}\int_0^1 e^{zu} u^{2\alpha-1} (1-u)^{1-2\alpha} du
=
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(2\alpha)_n}{(n+1)!} \frac{z^n}{n!}$$

2)simplify special cases, $J(k=1,\alpha)$ and $J(k=2,\alpha)$ are very important.

3) finding and proving any relation, like relation $J(k=1,\alpha)$ and $J(k=1,1-\alpha)$ , very appreciated.It seems for even $k$ 
$$J(k,\alpha)=J(k,1-\alpha)$$

and for odd $k$

$$J(k,\alpha)=-J(k,1-\alpha)$$ .

My try to show $J_{(k,1-\alpha)}=(-1)^k J_{(k,\alpha)}$:

define $M(a,b,z)={}_1F_1(a , b ,z)$

By [Kummer's_transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confluent_hypergeometric_function#Kummer's_transformation) 
$$M(a,b,z)=e^z M(b-a,b,-z)$$
 and
\begin{eqnarray}
e^{ik\pi}=\cos(k\pi)+i\sin(k\pi)=\cos(k\pi)=\left\{
\begin{array}{cc}
-1 & k\in 1,3,\cdots \\
1 & k\in 2,4,\cdots 
\end{array}
\right.
\end{eqnarray}

\begin{eqnarray}
J_{(k,\alpha)}&=&M(2\alpha , 2 ,ik\pi) +M(2\alpha , 2 ,-ik\pi)
\\ &=&
e^{ik\pi}M(2-2\alpha , 2 ,-ik\pi) +e^{-ik\pi}M(2-2\alpha , 2 ,ik\pi)
\\ &=&
e^{ik\pi}M(2(1-\alpha) , 2 ,-ik\pi) +e^{-ik\pi}M(2(1-\alpha) , 2 ,ik\pi)
\\ &=&
\left\{
\begin{array}{cc}
-M(2(1-\alpha) , 2 ,-ik\pi) -M(2(1-\alpha) , 2 ,ik\pi) & k\in 1,3,\cdots \\
M(2(1-\alpha) , 2 ,-ik\pi) +M(2(1-\alpha) , 2 ,ik\pi) & k\in 2,4,\cdots 
\end{array}
\right.
\\ &=&
\left\{
\begin{array}{cc}
-J(k,1-\alpha) & k\in 1,3,\cdots \\
J(k,1-\alpha) & k\in 2,4,\cdots 
\end{array}
\right.
\end{eqnarray}
is this true(valid proof)?

By this result, choosing  $\alpha=.5$

$$J(k,.5)=0$$

Answer (score 2):

**coment on $\alpha = 1/2$**
When $\alpha = 1/2$, note
$$
{}_1F_1(2\alpha;2;z) = {}_1F_1(1;2;z) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{z^n}{(n+1)!} = \frac{e^z-1}{z}
$$
so that
$$
{}_1F_1(2\alpha;2;i k \pi)+{}_1F_1(2\alpha;2;-i k \pi)
=\frac{e^{i k \pi}-1}{i k \pi}+\frac{e^{-i k \pi}-1}{-i k \pi}
=\frac{e^{i k \pi}-e^{-i k \pi}}{ik\pi} - \frac{1-1}{ik\pi}
=\frac{2\sin(k\pi)}{k\pi}
$$
This is true for real $k\ne0$.  If $k =1,2,3\cdots$ then we get $J_{k,1/2} = 0$.

---

Similarly, when $\alpha = 1$ we get $J_{(k,1)} = 2 \cos(k\pi)$.

---

**another note**

from
$$
{}_1F_1(2\alpha , 2 ,z)=\frac{1}{\Gamma(2\alpha)\Gamma(2-2\alpha)}\int_0^1 e^{zu} u^{2\alpha-1} (1-u)^{1-2\alpha} du
$$
we get
$$
{}_1F_1(2\alpha , 2 ,i\pi k)+{}_1F_1(2\alpha , 2 ,-i\pi k)
=\frac{2}{\Gamma(2\alpha)\Gamma(2-2\alpha)}\int_0^1 \cos({\pi k u}) u^{2\alpha-1} (1-u)^{1-2\alpha} du
$$
so this question is very close to [$I_k=\int_0^1 \frac{1}{\mathbf{B}(\alpha , \beta )} \cos^k (\pi \theta) \theta^{\alpha -1} (1-\theta)^{\beta -1}d\theta $](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3498463/442)

Comment: Thank you very much